# Modify Nested attribute array before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I am trying to modify nested attributes before they are saved in my database. The idea is that if someone has already submitted a costume with a given `cid` in the costume database, we should pull that one and use it for the current agreement. However, through debugging, I've found that the nested attributes array doesn't change at all. Any thoughts?

Thanks!
Matt

```
app/models/agreement.rb
class Agreement < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :get_costumes

  has_and_belongs_to_many :costumes, join_table: :agreement_costumes  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :costumes, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['cid'].blank? }

  has_many :drycleans
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :drycleans, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

  def get_costumes
    self.costumes.map! { |costume|
      unless Costume.where(cid: costume.cid).nil?
        Costume.where(cid: costume.cid).first
      end
    }
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your unless-condition is never `true`. With a where-statement you get always an ActiveRecord. And also a empty ActiveRecord is not `nil`.

Try to change that condition to:

```
unless Costume.where(cid: costume.cid).count == 0
```

Or to:

```
unless Costume.find_by_cid(costume.cid).nil?
```

Comment: The issue isn't getting into the unless condition, we get there fine. But the value of `costume` never changes even though I return a value.

Comment: Made the change and still no luck.